# Make CloudFlare cache everything

Tags: nginx, caching, cloudflare

Basically i configured my CloudFlare rule to cache everything * domain.com/assets/ *

But anytime i download these assets on a device the 'CF-Cache-Status' stays on 'DYNAMIC' instead of HIT/MISS.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Page Rule Screenshot

[image: 1]

CloudFlare Cache Analytics Screenshot

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it was just an unsupported HTTP port, seems like CloudFlare only supports caching on 443 and 80/8080

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/japan/*` instead of `/japan*`. If this doesn't work, please share the entire page rule (you can use example.com instead of your domain) but there is a star in the beginning. So need to evaluate that as well.